# Connecting to mySQL on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

So I'm having an issue connecting to a mySQL database I created on my local host using XAMPP. The DB itself is set up fine on 127.0.0.1, but I had to use port 8000 (instead of 80) to get it to start in XAMPP.

```
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost:8000","","");
 if (!$con) {
   die('Connection failed.' . mysql_error());
 }
```

The above doesn't work, the browser times out after a few seconds saying it cannot display the webpage (note that it doesn't give the die message). I have also tried 127.0.0.1:8000 but no luck. Creating a user in phpMyAdmin and entering the credentials didn't achieve anything either.

If I take out the port and just use:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
```

This connects, but I can't seem to select my database because I don't think it's connecting to the right server!

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Do not use mysql_*it is deprecated
2. Port 8000 is for your server not mysql. Default mysql port  3306

You better of using PDO

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

Answer (score 1):

The port for MySQL is 3306. But you dont have to use that in your php code.

The reason why you cannot select your database is because you never specified that in your script. Hence, try the mysql_select_db function.

Like so:

```
mysql_connect('localhost','user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('database_name');
```

If you plan on using this code for a bigger system, its better to use prepared statements like madara-uchiha suggested. It wont be long until these functions will print depreciation notices in your application ;)

Answer (score 1):

remove port 8000 .This is not mysql port.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use *mysqli*

```
<?php $con = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "dbName");
if ($con->connect_errno) {
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (".$con->connect_errno.")".$con->connect_error;
}
?>
```